# Is ||w|| in libsvm...is it a constant value?

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

So I understand that with SVM ||w|| is the norm to the hyperplane. I'm wondering though, if this ||w|| ever changes in LibSVM. I ask because I'm wanting to find the distance from certain vectors to the hyperplane. The problem with that is that MATLAB LibSVM doesn't natively do this. They, though, do give decision values that are related to the distance and ||w||.

tldr; ||w||--->LibSVM-->is this value constant?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously **not**. The norm of normal to the hyperplane is **the whole point of the SVM optimization**. I would say it is the only thing truly "variable" in the SVM. What is this model doing is trying to minimize this term, so it **cannot be constant**.

Comment: I mean once the model is set...So when viewing the prediction decisions which depend on ||w||. Is that constant?

Comment: once the model is trained **all** the parameters (w,b,alpha,C,gamma,d,kernel) are constant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @lejlot. So, to ask you another question :D...

if the decision value from svmpredict is distance*|w| then I could find which testing points are in between the two margins by inputting the support vectors of my model along with my test points into svmpredict and then find the decision points that are less than those of my support vectors?

Comment: "True" support vectors have distance*||w||=1 by definition. Point "in the margin" are those which decision function is (up to sign) smaller than 1.